# I'm getting error when i sudo apt update: E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/resin-io/debian stable Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates

When I try to update
$sudo apt update
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/resin-io/debian stable Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran
$ grep -ir "dl.bintray.com"
I found the offending line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/etcher.list
I just commented the line out with a #, and the update ran without a problem